# Setting standard signal SIGIO in GNU

Tags: c, io, signals, gnu

I found SIGIO signal documented in GNU library. It is stated that there is a possibility the system to send a signal whenever I have input (particularly in socket).
According to documentation to create such signal I should set O_ASYNC flag to corresponding filedescritor.
My problem is that my GNU version (gcc 6.3.0) doesn't recognize such a keyword:

> error: ‘O_ASYNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)

I used following block to set a flag:

```
/* Set socket status async */
int status = fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);;
if (status < 0) error("Can't set async mode");
else printf("Async is set for signal %d\n", SIGIO);
```

I use Cigwin GCC 6.3.0

The code is below:

```
static void OnTimer(int sig)
{
   /* write request to socket BIO */
}
static void OnTick(int sig)
{
   char read[BUFSIZE] = {};
   int received;

    received = SSL_read(ssl, read, sizeof(read));
    /* Handle errors here */
    /* print the server's reply */
    printf("%s\n\n", read);
}

void connectSSL()
{
    /* do all socket set-up and connection */

    /* Establish handler for I/O signal */
    saction.sa_flags = 0;
    saction.sa_handler = OnTick;
    sigemptyset(&saction.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&saction.sa_mask, SIGALRM);
    if (sigaction(SIGIO, &saction, NULL) == -1) error("sigaction");
    else printf("OnTick handler created\n");

    /* Set socket status async */
    int status = fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0) | FASYNC);
    if (status < 0) error("Can't set async mode");
    else printf("Async is set for signal %d\n", SIGIO);

    /* Select the process to receive the signal */
    int process = fcntl(sockfd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    if (process < 0) error("Can't set address process");
    else printf("Process %d is set\n", getpid());

    /* do the rest SSL staff here */
}

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    sigset_t mask, oldmask;
    /* Wait for OnTimer event*/
    sigemptyset(&oldmask);
    sigaddset(&oldmask, SIGALRM);
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGIO);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
    connectSSL();
    createTimer(500000000);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nWaiting OnTimer %d\n", count + 1);
        sigsuspend(&oldmask);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to my actual answer below: Signal-controlled I/O in my experience opens up more problems than it actually solves. Once you make yourself knowledgeable on *what you may actually do* from a signal handler (look up "async-safe functions" for your OS), you might want to revert your design to something like `select`.

Comment: May be you right. Still I want to try it. Currently I can't manage to set this signal at all.

Comment: One reason I didn't fully happy with select is that select is called 4 times before there is real input message in socket. I suppose select continuously polls all I/O descriptors and ever revert 1 as all other fds are ready. I need faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to include `sys/fcntl.h`, either indirectly or directly. This is the place that defines the flags.

In case `O_ASYNC` is not defined, you can try and use the functionally equivalent predecessor of that flag, `FASYNC`.

Also make sure you have executed a

```
int flags;

/* Install signal handler here... */

/* Set flags to receive SIGIO (and SIGURG) signals */
flags = fcntl (F_GETFL, 0);
flags = fcntl (F_SETFL, flags | FASYNC);

/* Bind our process as receiver of SIGIO signals */
flags = fcntl (F_SETOWN, getpid ());
```

Comment: I have included fcntl.h, which used for O_NONBLOCK status flag. And I check all three files of fcntl.h, sys/fcntl.h and _default_fcntl.h. There is no mention of such macro like O_ASYNC.

Comment: Can you use `FASINC` instead? That should be the functionally equivalent predecessor.

Comment: `FASYNC` I meant to write

Comment: gcc recognized it and compiled file. but signal still doesn't work.

Comment: In this case you need to post more code, especially on how you install the signal handler. Did you use F_SETOWN to tell the system which process to notify?